# configuring wireless on command line interface

Tags: networking, wireless, command-line

Sometimes I boot into recovery kernel with CLI and networking for troubleshooting my laptop. So is there a way to connect to a wireless router or AP over command line? If it is possible what are the commands for the following:

1. To list available networks.
2. To connect to a network with: SSID, WPA2 key and DHCP mode.
3. A command to connect with: SSID, ad-hoc mode, ip-address, netmask, gateway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need the wpasupplicant package in order to connect to a network secured with wpa or wpa2.

Listed by order :
1 : `sudo iwlist scan`

2 : `sudo iwconfig <interface> essid "my network"` 
`iwpriv <interface> set AuthMode=<WPA2PSK or WPA2AES>`
`iwpriv <interface> set <WPA2PSK or WPA2AES>='WPA PASSPHRASE'`

3 : `sudo iwconfig <interface> essid "my network"`
`ifconfig <interface> inet <ip> netmask <mask>` 
then set a route to your gateway `route add <destination> gw <gateway ip>`

Comment: You maybe want to put a blank in front of the 'iwpriv' line containing your password. That way it won't show up in the history.

Comment: Do you need to do the iwconfig essid step twice?

Comment: In step 3, what is <destination>?  I am familiar with all of the above values, with the exception of that one.

Answer (score 1):

`nm-tool` or `sudo iwlist scan` will show you all available wireless networks.

There's a `cnetworkmanager` package that ought to let you control Network Manager from the command line.  I've never used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think iwlist and iwconfig does this. [Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=956761) is the forum that talks about this.